# Is the phrase, bacterially sealed, correct usage

Tags: adverbs

If one is referring to a connection between two metallic elements as being so tight that it excludes bacteria, would it be correct usage to say that the connection is bacterially sealed? It sounds incorrect, as if the connection is sealed by bacteria.

Comment: Consider "bacteria-proof sealing." https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&q=%22bacteria-proof+sealing%22

Comment: It sounds like the OP is after a term similar to *hermetically sealed*, but with reference to bacteria. That is, he's not guaranteeing any form of hygiene, just saying that even bacteria can't get in.

Comment: I had considered this descriptive phrase because it contains the exact meaning I wish to capture. I rejected it as being a bit awkward. Hermetically sealed is a smoother expression but doesn't convey the bacteria excluding idea sufficiently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Sealed from bacteria* would be more appropriate.

I would prefer calling such a surface *aseptic* (OED:)

> aseptic, *a:*
>
> Free from contamination caused by harmful bacteria, viruses, or other
>   microorganisms; surgically sterile or sterilized.

Comment: This doesn't quite describe the nature of the connection in question, but it's close. The perfect answer would be an adjective that conveys the idea: no bacteria can pass through this very tight connection. Unless I see a better suggestion I will use this.